# Problems with certificate authentication for grpc client

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, grpc, client-certificates

I've created a demo solution with a gRPC client (console application) and a gRPC server application. (the provided template for it on .NET Core 3)

I'm trying to test certificate authentication between the two, but for some reason it fails with the following error:

`AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."`

My `Program.cs` for the server

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(o =>
            {
                o.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(o =>
                {
                    o.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate;
                    o.ServerCertificate = <MyCertificateWithPrivateKey>;
            });
        });
```

In the client application I pass the very same certificate inside an HttpHandler, which is passed to the channel I create i.e

```
GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:5001", new GrpcChannelOptions
            {
                HttpHandler = handler
            });
```

My server's startup class:

```
 public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddGrpc();
            services.AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCertificate();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapGrpcService<GreeterService>();

                endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client. To learn how to create a client, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086909");
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

Appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest sample code.  Recently TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 was discontinued and you must use TLS 1.2.  Also CORE 2.0 features have been changed in Core 3.0 and Core 3.1.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/2.2-3.0

Comment: @jdweng thank you, but the projects I made are brand new for demo purposes. They are not projects written before on NET Core 2.0 etc.

Comment: Make sure you are working with all the windows patches and latest gRPC library.  And server is using latest libraries.  Lots of people in the last few weeks had to do updates to get existing code working.  See : https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth/

Comment: This looks like it could be an issue with the certificate. Make sure the certificate is not expired and "localhost" is trusted on the SSL certificate. If you are using Visual Studio, try running your client as an administrator. Additionally, it may help to debug and identify if the exception is being raised on the client-side or server-side.

Comment: @AngelaYang ah, perhaps that's the problem then. The certificate does not trust localhost at all. It trusts other kinds of domains. So I can't just plug in a certificate in `ServerCertificate`, if the certificate itself doesn't answer to the hostname? It's weird because you'd expect the asp.net core project to throw an error, rather than an error to be thrown to clients attempting to authorize with it?